# why do i get the error as 'cannot find symbol'?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Inheritance.java file

```
      package oops.Inheritance;

       public class Inheritance {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Teacher t=new Teacher("gopi");

        t.name="ravi";
        t.eat();
        t.walk();
        t.teach();
        Singer s=new Singer("rock");
        s.name="arjun";
        s.eat();
        s.walk();

        person p =new person("jack");
        //person p=t;//upcasting

        //Teacher t=(Teacher)p;//downcasting

        // boolean yo = t instanceof Teacher;//to fine whether t is is instance of teacher
        // System.out.println(t instanceof Teacher);//true
        // System.out.println(s instanceof Singer);//true
        // System.out.println(t instanceof person);//true
        // System.out.println(p instanceof Teacher);//flase



    }
}
```

The error is

```
D:\study files\java files\oops\Inheritance>javac Inheritance.java
```

Inheritance.java:5: error: cannot find symbol

```
        Teacher t=new Teacher("gopi");
        ^
```

symbol:   class Teacher

location: class Inheritance

Inheritance.java:5: error: cannot find symbol

```
    Teacher t=new Teacher("gopi");
                  ^
```

symbol:   class Teacher

location: class Inheritance

Inheritance.java:10: error: cannot find symbol

```
    Singer s=new Singer("rock");
    ^
```

symbol:   class Singer

location: class Inheritance

Inheritance.java:10: error: cannot find symbol

```
    Singer s=new Singer("rock");
                 ^
```

symbol:   class Singer

location: class Inheritance

Inheritance.java:15: error: cannot find symbol

```
    person p =new person("jack");
    ^
```

symbol:   class person

location: class Inheritance

Inheritance.java:15: error: cannot find symbol

```
    person p =new person("jack");
                  ^
```

symbol:   class person

location: class Inheritance

6 errors

person.java

```
     package oops.Inheritance;



      public class person {

      protected String name;

        public person(String name){

        this.name=name;
        System.out.println("Inside person constructor");   
      }

      public void walk(){
      System.out.println("person"+name+"person is walking");
    }
      public void eat(){
      System.out.println("person"+name+"person is eating");
     }
      public static void laughing(){
      System.out.println("person is laughing");
         }

      }
```

Teacher.java

```
      package oops.Inheritance;

      public class Teacher extends person{//inheriting from person

      public Teacher(String name){

      super(name);//calls the constructor in the parent class

      System.out.println("Inside teacher constructor");   
      }

       public void teach(){
       System.out.println(name+"Teacher is teaching");
       }

       public void eat(){
       super.eat();//to access the parent class i.e, here person           class
       System.out.println("teacher"+name+"is eating");
         }
        }
       }
```

singer.java

```
       package oops.Inheritance;

       public class Singer extends person{//inheriting from person

       public Singer(String name){

        super(name);//calls the the constructor in parent class

        System.out.println("Inside singer constructor");   

      }

        public void sing(){
        System.out.println("Singer is singing");
    }

        public void eat(){
        System.out.println("teacher"+name+"is eating");
    }
}
```

I'm running this program in vscode the latest version.
every time it works but when I import the classes from the other package I get the above-mentioned error.

Comment: Are all these classes in the same package? If not, did you import them?

Comment: yes they are in same package.As you can see in the code.

Comment: You're in the wrong directory. You should be at the root of the package hierarchy. `cd ..` and use `javac Inheritance/Inheritance.java`.

Comment: You should be in the `java files` directory when doing `javac`.

Comment: if I am in a wrong directory it should have given 'main class couldn't found' but that's not the case.And i'm sure i'm not in wrong directory

Comment: i get the same error again

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xsRX9gF.png

Comment: above is error link

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @OP your comment is meaningless. You can't get a 'main class not found' error until you execute, and you can't execute until you compile, and you can't presently compile. You are still in the wrong directory. You should be in the `java files` directory, i.e. `cd ..\..` and issue `javac oop/Inheritance/Inheritance.java`. And then `java oop.Inheritance.Inheritance`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/z1GoQwH.png.  I did exactly same as you mentioned.Any sorry about my comment i'm new to java.

Comment: same error again.

Comment: Are all these source files in `D:\study files\java files\oops\Inheritance`? If not, why not? And what exactly does 'every time it works' mean in your question?

Comment: i mean when i run some other java file it does not give me the error.And I found this error when my main class file and sub class file are seperate.

Comment: That's one answer to two or three questions.

Comment: these are not three different questions.I have provided the code for clarity.

Comment: ***I*** asked ***you*** two or three different questions, and you answered one of them.

Comment: they are in this directory D:\study files\java files\oops\Inheritance.?I couldn't get your second question

Comment: My second question starts with 'if not', and therefore doesn't apply, but surely you can find a question when required? They end with question marks.

Comment: why this is not working?

Comment: Is anything stopping you from using a proper IDE such as for example Eclipse? Then you would not have this problem.

Comment: The reason why use VS code is i can find terminal here. And in Eclipse when i excute the code i get something like Error: Could not find or load main. so i've started using vscode.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to fix the setup in Eclipse so that that works. Once that problem is solved, you don't need to worry about how to compile anymore.

In any case, to answer the question you asked:

In order to compile your files from the command line, you need to be in the `java files` directory. This needs to be your working directory since it is the root directory containing your outermost package, `oops`.

Then you need to compile `person` first. You cannot compile `Inheritance` alone. The compiler will only recognize the classes used in `Inheritance` — `person`, `Teacher` and `Singer` — after each of them has been compiled. Use the relative path name to the file:

```
javac oops/Inheritance/person.java
```

(use backslash instead of slash if on Windows). After `person` compile `Teacher` and `Singer` (in any order). Finally compile `Inheritance`.

**Edit:** This worked on my BSD Unix with bash:

> ```
> $ ls oops/inheritance/
> Inheritance.java  Singer.java
> Person.java       Teacher.java
> $ javac oops/inheritance/Person.java 
> $ javac oops/inheritance/Teacher.java oops/inheritance/Singer.java 
> $ javac oops/inheritance/Inheritance.java 
> $ ls oops/inheritance/
> Inheritance.class Person.java     Teacher.class
> Inheritance.java  Singer.class        Teacher.java
> Person.class      Singer.java
> $ java oops.inheritance.Inheritance
> Inside Person constructor
> Inside teacher constructor
> Personraviperson is eating
> teacherraviis eating
> Personraviperson is walking
> raviTeacher is teaching
> Inside Person constructor
> Inside singer constructor
> teacherarjunis eating
> Personarjunperson is walking
> Inside Person constructor
> $
> ```

Compared to your code I have used small `i` in the package name `inheritance` and upper case `P` in the class `Person`, both in accordance with Java naming conventions. I have also corrected the number of closing curly braces and similar tiny details that aren’t relevant to the problem of compiling and running.

What went wrong for you when you tried my suggestion, I am sorry, I cannot guess.

Comment: As u said i compiled person first,then when i compiled teacher class i get error asD:\study files\java files>javac oops/Inheritance/person.java

D:\study files\java files>javac oops/Inheritance/teacher.java
oops\Inheritance\teacher.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class Teacher extends person{//inheriting from person
                             ^
  symbol: class person
1 error

Comment: I have tried eclipse but i get this https://i.imgur.com/XypBk57.png

Comment: I saw your error message *cannot find symbol*, but I cannot reproduce it. As demonstrated in my edit. Sorry.

Comment: A wild guess: In your Java code you have `Teacher` with capital `T`. On your command line, `javac oops/Inheritance/teacher.java`, you have a small `t`. While Windows doesn’t mind, I don’t know whether `javac` does. Also how does Windows display/print the file name, upper or lower case `T`?

Comment: i used 'T' while compiling Teacher.java but it still does not work

Comment: And the produced `Teacher.class` file has uppercase `T` in its name? Then I am out of suggestions, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are going through Apni Kaksha Java Tustorials, here I've got your problem solved, below is my directory Structure

```
root
  |
  ->inheritance
    |
    person.java
    |
    teacher.java
    |
    MainClass.java
```

so what you need to do, being in root directory (not in inheritance directory)
run following commands

```
PS E:\Java> javac inheritance/person.java    
PS E:\Java> javac inheritance/teacher.java  
PS E:\Java> javac inheritance/MainClass.java
PS E:\Java> java inheritance/Mainclass
```

This will solve your problem

Happy Coding!!